# Spectator - leave input field

Tags: unit-testing, ag-grid-angular, angular-spectator

I am using Spectator to test my Angular application that uses ag-grid.
I am trying to click on a cell, input some value and leave that cell. ( press enter or click somewhere else on the page )

```
spectator.click('.ag-center-cols-container .ag-row:first-child .ag-cell');
spectator.typeInElement(
  'hello',
  '.ag-center-cols-container .ag-row:first-child .ag-cell input'
);
spectator.click();
```

The 2 first line work, I am able to select the first cell and then I am able to change the value. The problem is the 3rd line, I am unable to leave the input.

I tried the following as well: `spectator.keyboard.pressEnter();`

Comment: Same problem here. Did you found any solution? It doesn't trigger my (change)